# Не получается задать путь к properties файлу java, android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, properties

[image: Часть кода]

Подскажите, что не так? Пишу приложение под андроид, никак не могу загрузить properties файл, планируется подгрузить его в основном файле и использовать в других ссылаясь на статик основного. Prop лежит в одном каталоге с Class файлом. Пробовал по разному, со слешами\без кидал файл в android/assets и прописывал путь, ничего не помогает. При прописывании пути выдаёт ошибку о том что он не нашёл файл, если все остальные ресурсы имеют стандартный InternalPath, то путь к prop не понимаю как прописывать вообще.

При попытке воспользоваться 
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
не вызывается метод getResources()

Answer (score 0):

@Wack убери слеши перед именем файла,

```
InputStream is = Game.class.getResourceAsStream("card.properties");
```

файл должен лежать в ресурсах по такому же пути, что и загружающий его класс.. про андроид ничего не знаю, просто по скрину странная структура каталогов, может в нем так и должно быть..

```
src\main\java\com\deckgame\chaos\Game.java
src\main\resources\com\deckgame\chaos\card.properties
```

вот пример, все работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слеши убирал, ситуация не меняется, при чём при использовании getResourseAsStream он постоянно выдаёт NullPointerException, а не как с InputStream, при использовании InputStream он пишет что не может найти файл (Где бы я его не ложил и какой путь не прописывал)
Кстати при вызове параметров из properties когда он лежит рядом с основным классом (который его вызывает) эти параметры подсвечиваются как используемые

Comment: в обычном проекте все работает.. у тебя не работает, в готовом приложении ?

Comment: вот простой пример.. все работает